# DX Reports alternatives?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, reporting

I'm looking for DevExpress Reports framework alternatives.

We currently use it in our project, but with a number of flaws. The largest one is that we can't get reports rendering to PDF with proper Chinese symbols support. Instead, we get squares or just nothing instead of text. Also, we often experience a number of performance issues when creating large reports which we cannot address to our code directly.

So, we are looking for reporting framework that:

1. Can use our own Data Access library and our data model (Entity Framework + custom models) instead of direct SQL queries;
2. Can render reports to HTML *and* PDF;
3. Can render dynamic images (we have some images creating externally);
4. Can use any character set, at least latin, cyrillic, chinese, indian.

Optionally (not necessary):

1. With Visual Studio designer support (or any other designer)
2. Free
3. Open source or at least well community supported

I was googling and reading articles for a few hours and found [this article](http://www.butleranalytics.com/reporting-net/) useful. As I see in it, the most obvious alternative is Telerek's DevCraft, but the description on the site is quite limited and I just can't be sure. Also, it's *a bit* pricey.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

see tools "Enterprise" project: 
These components are used to create our ERP systems

1. Stimul-Report https://www.stimulsoft.com/en - best designer and reports
2. Fast-Report .NET - reliable and functional system, worked on many projects
3. GrapeCity Active Report - not used, but this component was one of the major options for selection. our orientation was .NET and support cyrillic